# how to add circular progress spinner in material design toolbar

Tags: android, material-design

i am using mateial design toolbar. i want to add a circular progress spinner on the toolbar which will execute till a background task is completed. How can i implement this progress bar.

```
private Toolbar toolbar;   
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
toolbar.setTitle("New Appointments");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/material_green_500"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<!-- Color is Brown 500 -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateTint="#795548"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: thanks.. but how do i add it my onPreExecute() method

Comment: you can get id of progressbar and make visible in onpreexecute otherwise visibility will be invisible

Comment: set the visibility of the progess bar in xml to gone --> android:visibility="gone"
Then in your method onPreExecute(), make it visible ---> progessBar.setVisibilty(View.Visible);
Finally set the visibilty to gone in the onPostExecute() method --> progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);